# Remove the "salesforce" word in sender address for email which is sending from SF

Tags: email

we configured the different workflow in salesforce.
Salesforce are sending emails from salesforce server. Sender email address is look like below.

[image]

I don't want **salesforce** word should be visible in the sender address.

I found the [Email Relay Activation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=email_relay.htm&siteLang=en_US&type=0) article. but not sure this will be the solution.

As per my knowledge to connect SMTP server we need to enter the username & poassword. SO where should we have to enter this.  In salesforce such option is not available. check below screenshot [image]

Please suggest the workaround & Correct me if I'm missing something.

Comment: Have you looked into Org Wide Email Addresses?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Tried. but no any impact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm seeing via ***0cg7gri2umy6l.36-1gcueea0.na30.bnc.salesforce.com*** , This is a security feature set by Gmail which displays the full email address of the sender.

"Gmail detected that the email was sent via another mail service. This means that the sender may be using a third-party email service to generate this message. For example, the message may have been sent through a social networking site which offers an email service or sent through a mailing list that you’re subscribed to.

Gmail displays this information because many of the services that send emails on behalf of others don’t verify that the name that the sender gives matches that email address. We want to protect you against misleading messages from people pretending to be someone you know."

For more information please visit: 
http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&ctx=mail&answer=1311182

Gmail recipient- Why am I seeing "via" followed by d.bnc.salesforce.com. 
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Gmail-recipient-Why-am-I-seeing-via-followed-by-d-bnc-salesforce-com&language=en_US

So here you need to setup the DKIM key feature provided by saelsforce.

Check [Setup DKIM key](http://c.na43.visual.force.com/apex/Introduce_Me_Requireds?lionid=00QF000000TSSnH) article for the steps.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the Salesforce sending address details in the email envelope, you have to use the relay option indeed. This potentially also increases deliverabilty as some receiving agents mark email 'send on behalf' as suspicious. However, the SMTP server you relay to has to allow unauthenticated sending, and not a lot of providers go along with that. Some of the premium smtp providers do however, so you best google for this if you don't own an smtp server.